# Is there a scheduled task object for python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have multiple python scripts that run overnight, via the Scheduled Task. What I want to do is a run another python script that runs after these scripts that gets information about that particular task and gives me information about the script time, script name, whether it ran successfully etc.

Using python how do i get access to these properties? What object is can I use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own logmanager class! when you run your script for each thing that was executed, you can write in a log file.
For example write an LogManager:

```
class LogManager():
    def get_time():
        # via time,date lib

    def get_script_name():
        # via os, path, system libs

    def get_pid():
        # via os, system libs

    def append_all_information_in_file():
        log = open("logfile", "a")
        log.write(get_time(), get_script_name(), get_pid())
        log.close()
```

And if you run your scripts, you can inherit the from the LogManager class that exactly Logs Information what you want. I hope I have understood your question correctly and the answer was helpful!

Comment: Thanks, we are doing something similar at the moment with writing to a log file but we want to get it directly from the scheduled task, I have found code on this link http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/72f419fc-7b29-4a67-983d-7546e643b2e7 but nothing gets printed.